# set showPii in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, passport.js, passport-azure-ad

I’m configuring my passport/express/node azure app service website for single-tenant azure ad logins.  I can sign in successfully on my localhost, but when I publish the site, I get `{"code":400,"message":"IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden]'."}`

I think I need set showPII somewhere to see that PII and diagnose/fix the issue.  How can we control this flag in a node azure?

Comment: Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12552#issuecomment-491314107).

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure that's relevant information, but I haven't been successful with it yet.  I've tried setting passport OIDCStrategy issuer parameter to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/e...3` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/e...3/v2.0` or `https://sts.windows.net/e...3/v2.0` and I've set the Manifest's `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` in Azure AD to `2` and various permutations.  I cannot find where that "+ Add issuer" interface exists.  There has been no change in my callback route's behavior through any of it.

Comment: Could you please provide your code of how to configure OIDCStrategy or BearerStrategy

Comment: Has anyone figured out how you set this property? I am using OIDC and getting this error as well...

Comment: The following thread is one way to troubleshoot this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670625/4200557