# How to solve 'PII is hidden' for node/express

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a node-api using express hosted on azure. Im using Azure AD for authentication. When i try to debug using postman i get error-responses like this

```
 "message": "IDX10511: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: '[PII is hidden]'. \nkid: '[PII is hidden]'. \nExceptions caught:\n '[PII is hidden]'.\ntoken: '[PII is hidden]'."
```

The error itself is something i can figure out (hopefully), but i need to be able to display the PII, how do i manage that?

Edit after comment:

Ok so i'll try to explain.

1. I have an angular front-end using msal with loginpopup(Authsettings).

   ```
   export const OAuthSettings = {
     appId: '*************', 
     redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
     authority : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/***tenant***/",
     scopes: [
       "user.read",
       "openid",
       "profile",
       "mailboxsettings.read",
       "calendars.readwrite"
     ]
   };
   ```
2. i get the access-token after login with my business-account.
3. Now i want to call my api, which is (should be) protected by azure ad. Then i get errors. Obviously something is not configured correctly. just dont know what or how to debug.

Comment: How do you set up the `scope`?

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered similar questions before, and this is usually an error caused by `scope`.

You need to expose the api of the **node-api application** protected by Azure. Then change the `scope` to: `{your api application client id}/{scope name}`.

```
export const OAuthSettings = {
  appId: '*************', 
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  authority : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/***tenant***/",
  scopes: [
    "{your api application client id}/user.read"
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hey, i already have an access-token retrieved from Microsoft Graph. My plan is to use that to access my API.

Comment: @KimR  Which api do you want to call ? Do you want to call ms graph api? Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @KimR  What you get is the token of ms graph api, you cannot use it to call custom api.

Comment: nevermind the part about MS graph. I misspoke.
i use the token to access MS graph actually

Comment: so how should i configure the scope?

Comment: @KimR  Do you want to call Node-api? Have you exposed the api in Azure?

Comment: Ok, i think i was able to fix that. now i get "IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'."
So how do i fix it with the audience?

Comment: yes i have exposed it, 
Looks like this: api://****-*****-****-****-*******/user.read

Comment: @KimR  Change your `scope` to this:  `scopes: [
    "api://****-*****-****-****-*******/.default"
  ]`.

Comment: I did.. then i get the error mentioned in a comment further up

Comment: @KimR  Is it still the original error? Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your token and provide screenshots.

Comment: no its this: 
"IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden]'." 

Don't want to share token here, sry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230030/discussion-between-kimr-and-carl-zhao).